# Java Spring and WordPress integration - Single-Sign On

Tags: wordpress, spring, spring-security, single-sign-on, jasig

I have an application which is completely written in Java with Spring framework. Right now I need to integrate this application with some other application that is written on WordPress. I need to seamlessly support the same user database for both of these application. I understand that I need some kind of Single-Sign On(SSO) that is supported of Spring(can be used with Spring Security) and WordPress.

Right now Spring application manages users via own Spring OAuth2 Authorization server. Is it possible to use this server in a separate WordPress application ?

Could you please recommend some SSO solution for this case ?

**UPDATED**

Maybe it is possible to use CAS [Jasig](http://jasig.github.io/cas/4.1.x/index.html) for this purpose ? Do we have support of Jasig for WP and Spring ?

If so I have an additional question about Jasig CAS architecture - where users for WP and Spring MVC applications must be stored ? I mean it is a single store(for example the same mysql database) or it can(must) be a different stores for each application ?

Comment: Depends on the context of serve - wordpress can take and send rest API requests so you could authorize WP to access your app through this

Comment: There are two different web applications(Spring MVC and Wordpress), How to implement SSO for both of them ? I mean user registered/logged in  can access Spring MVC application and Wordpress application simultaneously.

Comment: I also have this question (although I don't use Spring): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39247414/log-user-into-wordpress-blog-via-java-web-app. I suggest one method for how to execute this in the question.